# Verifying assetlinks.json gives ERROR_CODE_MALFORMED_CONTENT

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm trying to set up an assetlinks.json file on my web server to indicate that deep links should be handled by the mobile app and that login credentials should be shared between the website and mobile device on Android 8.

I have the assetlinks.json file hosted on my dev server (https://devtesting.narrpr.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json).

```
[{
        "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "web",
            "site": "https://devtesting.narrpr.com/"
        }
    },
    {
        "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds", "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
            "target": {
                "namespace": "android_app",
                "package_name": "com.rpr.mobile",
                "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
                    "D3:7B:D8:D7:47:AF:08:2E:BA:EF:02:96:8C:F2:3A:1A:46:F9:B0:81:E9:E3:6D:BA:01:3C:00:59:95:39:8D:21"
                ]
            }
    }
]
```

When I execute [this url](https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://devtesting.narrpr.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls) to test it, it gives an error:

```
{
  "maxAge": "599.999999890s",
  "debugString": "********************* ERRORS *********************\n* Error: invalid_argument: Could not parse statement list (not valid JSON): \\357\\273\\277[{\\r\\n\\t\\t\\\"relation\\\": [\\\"delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds\\\"],\\r\\n\\t\\t\\\"target\\\": {\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"namespace\\\": \\\"web\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"site\\\": \\\"https://devtesting.narrpr.com/\\\"\\r\\n\\t\\t}\\r\\n\\t},\\r\\n\\t{\\r\\n\\t\\t\\\"relation\\\": [\\\"delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds\\\", \\\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\\\"],\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"target\\\": {\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"namespace\\\": \\\"droid\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"package_name\\\": \\\"com.rpr.mobile\\\",\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"sha256_cert_fingerprints\\\": [\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"D3:7B:D8:D7:47:AF:08:2E:BA:EF:02:96:8C:F2:3A:1A:46:F9:B0:81:E9:E3:6D:BA:01:3C:00:59:95:39:8D:21\\\"\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t]\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t}\\r\\n\\t}\\r\\n] [0] while fetching Web statements from https://devtesting.narrpr.com./.well-known/assetlinks.json (which is equivalent to 'https://devtesting.narrpr.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json') using download from the web (ID 1).\n********************* INFO MESSAGES *********************\n* Info: No statements were found that match your query\n",
  "errorCode": [
    "ERROR_CODE_MALFORMED_CONTENT"
  ]
}
```

In the debug line it says that it's not valid json, however jsonlint begs to differ. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I had the same issue when copying and pasting from Android Studio.  I changed the encoding to UTF-8 in VS Code and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After generating the assetlinks.json file through Android Studio (instead of manually), it started working. Not sure if I missed content or if it was an issue with windows text encoding.

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.rpr.mobile",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["D3:7B:D8:D7:47:AF:08:2E:BA:EF:02:96:8C:F2:3A:1A:46:F9:B0:81:E9:E3:6D:BA:01:3C:00:59:95:39:8D:21"]
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "web",
    "site": "https://devtesting.narrpr.com"
  }
},
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.rpr.mobile",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["D3:7B:D8:D7:47:AF:08:2E:BA:EF:02:96:8C:F2:3A:1A:46:F9:B0:81:E9:E3:6D:BA:01:3C:00:59:95:39:8D:21"]
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Android specification requires `android_app` as namespace.

```
- "namespace": "droid",
+ "namespace": "android_app",
```

Comment: After changing the namespace, it still gives the same "not valid JSON" error.

Answer (score 1):

Error is inside your file taken from a clipboard:

> Error: invalid_argument: Could not parse statement list (not valid JSON): \357\273\277[...

Remove wrong characters (\357\273\277) at the beginning of the file or create new one from scratch instead.